# SSRS expression based on Field value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

I have a matrix report. i am calculating by using this expression,

```
=switch(Fields!Type.Value = "ATHLETE",Sum(Fields!JnlAmt.Value)
,Fields!Type.Value = "Type",0.8*Sum(Fields!JnlAmt.Value)
,Fields!Type.Value = "VENUE", Sum(Fields!JnlAmt.Value))
```

Now i would like to find the difference of Athlete and Type

```
=Sum(Fields!JnlAmt.Value) [from Athlete] - 0.8*Sum(Fields!JnlAmt.Value) [from Type]
```

I need help to write an expression for this. If you need more information, let me know. Please any help, any taught is welocme.

Comment: how is your report template, how you are achieving these in `matrix` - dataset mapping and some sample data would help to understand the problem better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve that by using a conditionally `Sum()`. Despite I know nothing about grouping and data arrangement in your matrix, I think you are looking for this expression:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Type.Value="ATHLETE",Fields!JnlAmt.Value,0))-
0.8*Sum(IIF(Fields!Type.Value="Type",Fields!JnlAmt.Value,0))
```

I've created a simple matrix for example purpose.

[image]

```
6 - (0.8 * 15) = -6
```

Hopefully this what you are looking for, let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hey, i tried by using the above expression. I am just getting #error message.

Comment: @Hari, share a screenshot or a description of your matrix, the groups and the expressions in it.

Answer (score 0):

I used nothing instead of 0, it's worked for me. Thanks for your help.

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Type.Value="ATHLETE",Fields!JnlAmt.Value,nothing))-
0.8*Sum(IIF(Fields!Type.Value="Type",Fields!JnlAmt.Value,nothing))
```